# How can I provide multiple sorting options for a single column in a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable

I have a JTable that shows objects of multiple types.  I'd like to provide two ways to sort: by type (grouping like with like), by name alphabetically, or reverting to the default document-order based on how things were entered.

How can I leverage as much as possible of the existing visual and table model infrastructure, but provide those 3 options instead of just string sorting or not?  (I'm picturing either a right-click menu on the header with the 3 options, or perhaps just successive clicks switching modes, with a little indicator going from blank to "T" to "N" or something like that.)

Comment: I think it really depends on what you want. Anything is possible and can be done. You can also have a drop down list or do it like MS Excel user interface.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm picturing either a right-click menu on the header with the 3 options,

That is probably what I would suggest. Then when you select the option you set the Comparator for the sorter using `DefaultRowSorter.setComparator(...)` and then invoke the `sort()` method to do the sort based on the new Comparator.